# Can I do count (*) in the Lucene query string?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am working with a system where I can provide a Lucene query string, but have no access to the Lucene API itself. I only provide a query string and get a list of domain specific result objects.

From my reading so far, it seems that I cannot do the equivalent of a `select count(*) where ...` with just the query string, but I am not 100% sure that I understood. Is this correct?

Comment: are you looking for [count api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)? I did not understand your question completely.

Comment: So, I did actually read that page, and concluded that the count API doesn't give me a way to do a count *purely through the Lucene query string*. So the system I am in lets me specify a query string such as "(fieldName : someValue) and (otherField : otherValue)" but that's it. I have no access to any Lucene APIs at all.. all I can do is pass this query string in. So I was wondering if there was a way to do "count ((fieldName : someValue) and (otherField : otherValue))" or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, I think I got the question. I am not aware of anything like that but [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/count-equivilent-in-Solr-Lucene-td1730256.html) could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QueryParser syntax does not include any functions of that sort, no.

The Lucene API provides the count of total matches with it's result set.  Solr and ElasticSearch also return the count.  If the interface you are using doesn't expose that figure, there isn't any feature of the Lucene QueryParser syntax that will help you gain access to it.

Comment: Do you know if this is still unsupported (3 years later)? I am trying to graph the number of documents matching a lucene query, but clipping it at a maximum value, in Grafana (using the ElasticSearch plugin) and can't seem to find a way to do that.